# No test that you wouldn't have had done before

Tags: grammar, idioms, british-english, tenses, speech

> *No test that you wouldn't have had done before*
>
> https://youtu.be/4nm6Xaxvqd0?t=200 (3:20)

Is this phrase grammatical? There's no idiom such as *would (not) have* or [have done](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_done).

What about *No test you hadn't had done before*?

Comment: Are you certain that quote is a sentence? It looks like a noun phrase.

Comment: Of course, it's fine. That is not a test you wouldn't have had done before [now]. to have a test done, to not have a test done. In **speaking**, we often drop: "[That's] no test you wouldn't have had done before. The "That's" is implied.

Answer (score 1):

> No test that you wouldn't have had done before

The above is a prediction, i.e. "From my experience as an eye specialist I can predict/surmise that you will have had this test before".

Strictly speaking the original isn't a complete sentence. We can make it so in various ways, e.g.

*I shall administer no test that you wouldn't have had done before.*

*No test that you wouldn't have had done before will be given.*

*There will be no test that you wouldn't have had done before.*

Those are perfectly correct, complete sentences.

**Alternatives**

*No test that you *won't* have had done before.* (prediction)

*No test you haven't had done before.* (certainty/knowledge)

Comment: Do both _will_ and _would_ work in the positive, _A test you will/would surely have already had done_?

Comment: For me, the distinction is one of politeness. "would" is conditional (with an implied and unspecified condition) thus not requiring the patient to agree.

Comment: Then what's the modality of _would_ here, especially in relation to _will_?